# Food for thought, or otherwise

Tags: riddle

Here's my first riddle on Puzzling SE.

> They say I'm a ship
>   But I see no water for days
>   You may think you know me
>   From my cousin of holy ways
>
> Look for me in abandoned places
>   And you might find an obstacle or two
>   Its what keeps me going long
>   When the movers move

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are talking about

> A camel

*They say I'm a ship*

> A camel is also called as the "ship of the desert"

*But I see no water for days*

> There is no water in their habitat, the desert

*You may think you know me From my cousin of holy ways*

> The cousin of the camel is the llama. Llama ( Lama ) is a reference to Dalai Lama, the Buddhist Monk.

*Look for me in abandoned places*

> A desert is pretty abandoned.

*And you might find an obstacle or two Its what keeps me going long When the movers move*

> As Kevin Rubin has stated, " 'an obstacle or two' could be the camels' humps. These humps store water for the camel which helps them going long. "When the movers move" could mean the camel herders because they "move" the camel around by riding it.

Comment: Cousin of Holy Ways could be related to a donkey - Jesus riding into Jerusalem, etc.

Comment: "an obstacle or two" could be the camels' humps, which hold water to keep them going long.

Comment: You are right except for the reason for 'holy ways' and 'movers move'. Also, find the connect of the title.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Is the camel's "cousin" a llama? Also are the "holy ways" related with religion?

Comment: @KritixiLithos: Spot on! Now think about movers.

Comment: @KritixiLithos: You misunderstood the holy ways hint. It's a reference to the Dalai Lama (llama ~ Lama). Llama worship is not really common.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Aah, I see. So now, by movers do you mean human beings riding on the camel, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @KritixiLithos: "Movers" are people with a tendency to move. A community known to use camels a lot.

Comment: As Ogden Nash said: A one-l lama is a priest, a two-l llama is a beast, but I'll wager my pyjama, that there is no three-l lllama.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Do "movers" mean nomads, gypsies or other people?

Comment: @KritixiLithos: I was referring to nomads. Now for the title?

Comment: "These humps store water for the camel which helps them going long." Absolutely false. The humps store fat, this is what keeps the camel moving. Water is good to have of course but it can't provide the energy required to move, so the camel is better off with fat instead of water.

Answer (score 7):

Could it possibly be:

> A space ship or satellite?

They say I'm a ship
But I see no water for days

> Space ships are not used on water, but rather in space. (Where there isn't liquid water)

You may think you know me
From my cousin of holy ways

> I'm pretty sure everyone knows about normal water ships (boats, yachts etc.) which could be a cousin of a space ship.

Look for me in abandoned places
And you might find an obstacle or two

> If you look in space (which can be considered abandoned and empty), You will can see some objects (planets and stars). [Earth + moon/sun]

Its what keeps me going long
When the movers move

> The gravitational forces from the Earth and moon/sun are what keep space ships and satellites orbiting earth. Space ships can also be 'sling shot' by using gravitation forced of other heavy bodies.

Comment: In space, nothing is close ;P

Comment: @CodeNewbie It's possible that perhaps your puzzle has multiple valid solutions. :)

Comment: @fluffy: sure, if you stretch any clue to its lengths, you can make it fit to your answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

this is my first answer too (no questions yet)

> Relationship

They say I'm a ship
But I see no water for days

> the word ends in ship, but its not actually a ship

You may think you know me
From my cousin of holy ways

> Your cousins are you relations

Look for me in abandoned places
And you might find an obstacle or two

> not too sure about this

Its what keeps me going long
When the movers move

> When loved ones move away, if you keep things going, then you are in a long distance relationship